# Finfo_file on uploaded file to determine mime-type

Tags: php, linux, mime-types, fileinfo

Im trying to determine the mime-type of an uploaded file, i want to use fileinfo(), this is what ive been trying, it isnt working:

```
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['soup']['tmp_name'];
if(isset($uploadedfile))
{
    $uploadedname = $_FILES['soup']['name'];
    $file=$uploadedsong;
    $file.=$uploadedname;
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
```

Unfortunately the `finfo_file` doesnt seem to be running, Im assuming i have the following `$file` set incorrectly for this, is there a way i can do this properly with a newly uploaded file using `$_FILE` like this? or am i going at this problem the completely improper way. Using a file i have pre-set in another directly, and setting `$file="folder/file.doc"` works properly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should be passing the path to the finfo_file function not the filename.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_FILES['soup']['tmp_name'])) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['soup']['tmp_name']);
    if ($mime == 'application/msword') {
        //Its a doc format do something
    }
    finfo_close($finfo);
}
?>
```

Comment: In your php.ini file, make sure you have this entry: extension=fileinfo.so
or in windows: php_fileinfo.dll

Comment: Notice: it wont work correctly if the document is of type `xlsx`, `docx`, `pptx` e.t.c as it would return  `inode/x-empty` and `pdf` would return `text/html` rather than `application/pdf`

Comment: I have been looking for FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE example Thank you I found this.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `finfo()` `buffer()` function as well as `file_get_contents()` from the php platform as below

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mimetype = $finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($filename)); #gives you mime type
```

you need to be on `php 5.3` or higher and make sure you have the `finfo()` extension installed. for linux `extension=fileinfo`. and in windows: `php_fileinfo.dll`

you can have an array of accepted mime types and then check if it exists in that array

```
$acceptedMime = [];
if(in_array($mimetype, $acceptedMime, true) === true){
  #mime type is valid. Proceed!
}
```

Another alternative to avoid having to check mime types would be to store file uploads completely out of the document root folder.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a bit old, but since you're using the `$_FILES` super global, can you use the **type** key of the file array (i.e. `$_FILES['soup']['type']`) rather than having the server check once the file is uploaded?

Comment: Using the $_FILES array parameters to verify file type is spoof-able. That is why the finfo_file was created so we can actually check the binary of the file to determine if it is really for example an image file and not a php file with its file extension renamed to jpg, in which case the $_FILES array type would give jpg.

Comment: It's still quite easy to spoof the first bytes of a php files to trick finfo_file into thinking it's jpg.