# mime_content_type script replacement assistance

Tags: php, image, mime

I am running on a newer version of PHP, and with the depreciation of mime_content_type after loading a Github PHP script with two sections of this in it, I was wondering if someone might be able to help with what I can replace it with?

```
if (!function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
    throw new Exception('Program needs the FILEINFO PHP extension.');
}
```

and

```
$mimeType = mime_content_type($image);
if ($mimeType != 'image/png' && $mimeType != 'image/jpg' && $mimeType != 'image/gif') {
    user_error('Image mime type ' . $mimeType . ' not supported. Image will be ignored', E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Robert

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php doesn't appear to be deprecated?

Comment: This Stack page says it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809054/mime-content-type-function-not-working

Comment: That answer is wrong, if a function is deprecated you get a big red box on the manual page like: http://php.net/mysql_connect

Comment: Maybe it was deprecated at one point but definitely available in PHP7

Comment: I am running 5.3 and it does not like the function. Is there a conversion to FILEINFO

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9458554/2266583