# How to check PHP File Upload if file doesn't have extension?

Tags: php

Following this thread: [PHP file upload: mime or extension based verification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349473/php-file-upload-mime-or-extension-based-verification)
I assume that I need to check the file extension of the file that I am uploading, correct ?

I am trying to upload a binary file that results from a make file into a Raspberry using a PHP Interface.

This is the file in question:

```
Big_ppd_display_try1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=047e67dcea785cb3139bc690aebcf0d537ef40fe, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Following this thread: [php check file extension in upload form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456113/php-check-file-extension-in-upload-form)

I can try:

```
$allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

**But how do I tell PHP to only allow binary files like `Big_ppd_display_try1` that have no file extension** ?

Also, I am doing the upload from a Linux machine. How will that binary file look like on a Windows PC ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458418/finfo-file-on-uploaded-file-to-determine-mime-type

Answer (score 0):

To make sure file has no extension, compare it with `null`.
To check for `mime` tipe use `finfo_` functions:

```php
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if ($ext === null && $mime === 'application/octet-stream') {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: $ext === null assumes any files with no extension would work. But he only wants binary  files.

Comment: I don't think this will help me. I don't want to let the user the possibility to upload any kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `file` command if you are using linux like as bellow

```
  $command = "file $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']";
  shell_exec($command);
```

It will return a string like

> ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=047e67dcea785cb3139bc690aebcf0d537ef40fe, with debug_info, not stripped

You can evaluate the data returning the file type you want with this string.

Comment: How, exactly, can I evaluate the returning data ? The BuildID[sha1] will most probably be different each time. And how can I actually get that string that I should parse and check ?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that I need to check the file extension of the file that I am uploading, correct ?

No.

The file extension is an arbitrary part of the "suggested filename" which is *entirely under the control of the user*. The procedure you should be following is:

1. Inspect the contents of the file [as shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458418/finfo-file-on-uploaded-file-to-determine-mime-type).
2. Reject the file if the detected type is not in your allowed list.
3. Generate your own filename to save it to:

   - the extension should be based on the file type determined at step 1
   - the rest of the name might be based on what the user suggested, but should be filtered through a *whitelist* of allowed characters, e.g. replacing everything other than letters and numbers with `-`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best resolve but I have ended up checking if the file is an `application/octet-stream`:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['update_button']) && $_POST['update_button'] == 'Update') {
    if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
        $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK &&
        $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'] == "application/octet-stream")
    {
        // print_r($_FILES);
        echo "<br>Successful upload !<br> ";      
    } else {
        echo "<br>File was not uploaded !<br> ";
    }
}

?>
```

I have ditched checking for file extension or MIME type because I think these can be easily bypassed.

I am now trying to execute the file with a certain argument and check it's response.

This is the code I am working on now:

```
        $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
        // echo "<br>$fileTmpPath"."/$fileName<br>";
        $command = "sudo .$fileTmpPath"."/$fileName -argument";
        echo "<br>$command<br>";

        $response = exec($command, $full, $status);
        if($status != 0) {
            echo "<br>Something went wrong<br>";
        } else {
            echo "<br>$response<br>";
        }
```